# Subrings of rationals are noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $R$ is noetherian.

---

Since $1 \in R$ it follows, that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq R \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Consider an ideal $I \subseteq R$. Then $I':=I \cap \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal in PID $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence of the form $I'=(d)$.

I sense that it should be possible to conclude from here, that $I$ as well is finitely generated but I do not manage. Hints?

Comment: Interesting aside: A Dedekind ring is a Noetherian integral domain that is integrally closed and in which every prime is maximal. It is a fact that if $A$ is a Dedekind ring and $K$ its field of fractions, than any subring of $K$ containing $A$ is Dedekind, so this greatly generalizes the problem above.

Comment: Little detail: I think it is assumed that $1 \in R$ since a subring need not neccessarily be unitary, right? And the subring is assumed to be not \mathbb{Q} since this subring would not be noetherian.

Comment: @aieka Presumably $1 \in R$, as you wrote. Also, $\mathbf{Q}$ *is* noetherian (a field is noetherian).

Comment: Hi aieka: don't forget that you should upvote helpful answers, and accept whichever one you like by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, $I$ is also principal, generated by $d$. The inclusion $dR \subseteq I$ is obvious. To see the reverse inclusion, choose any $a \in I$. Write $a=x/y$ with $x,y \in \mathbf Z$ relatively prime. I claim that $y$ is a unit in $R$. Indeed, by Bezout's lemma we can write $ux + vy = 1$ for some integers $u,v$. Then

$$\frac{1}{y} = \frac{ux+vy}{y} = u\frac xy + v \in R$$

so $y$ is a unit in $R$. Now, since $x = ya \in \mathbf Z \cap I = (d)$, we can write $x=dc$ for some $c \in \mathbf Z$, and thus $$\frac xy = d\frac{c}{y} \in dR.$$

Comment: Thanks. a. What do you mean by relatively prime? b. I know $u$ and $v$ in $R$ but why do I know that $\frac{x}{y} \in R$?

Comment: Dear @aieka I mean coprime. Also, $x/y=a \in I \subseteq R$ by definition!

Comment: Ok. Oh true, overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Show that any such ring is a ring of fractions of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it. I mean it's a ring between the integers and the rationals and since the rationals are fractions of integers $R$ is a ring of fractions of integers.

Comment: @aieka user is referring to the concept of localization, which you might not have learned about.