# Subring of rationals is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> How to show that $R$ is a PID if $\mathbb{Z}\subset R\subset \mathbb Q$?

I tried as follows:

Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Then $\mathbb Z\cap I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z$. But I couldn't proceed further. Please help.

Comment: Particular case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137876/a-subring-of-the-field-of-fractions-of-a-pid-is-a-pid-as-well You can also use some ideas from  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570619/subrings-of-rationals-are-noetherian